# Final Builder Automation taking too much of time

Tags: finalbuilder

I am using final builder to compile all of my projects. It contains the actions like svn update, revert, assembly version switcher and copyright info changer. Previously it was working fine. But suddenly it is taking so much of time to complete each and every single action. 1 hour running is now taking more than 3 to 4 hours. But machine is running fast. Contains 4 GB RAM and i5 Processor.

Could anyone please let me know the solution for this?

Comment: use log output to check which actions taking too long and correct it.